# Fill Tabulator table with local json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, tabulator

I want to load a json file into my Tabulator table.
The programs.json is in the same directory as the html file.
My html code is rendering the table but i couldnt manage to load the local stored .json file.
There is a lot of documentation here http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data and http://tabulator.info/docs/3.5#set-data
The content of programs.json is following:

```
           [{
            "name": "Stomachache",
            "freq": "10000,5000,880,3000,95",
            "db": "XTR",
            "info": "Bauchschmerzen"
        }, {
            "name": "Headache",
            "freq": "380,2720,2489,2170,1800,1600,1550,880,832,787,776,727,465,444,1865,146,125,95,72,20,450,440,428,660",
            "db": "CAF",
            "info": "Kopfschmerzen"
        }, {
            "name": "Toothache",
            "freq": "3000,95,1550,880,787,776,727,650,625,600,28,35,28,110,100,60,428,680",
            "db": "XTR",
            "info": "Zahnschmerzen"
        }]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon"  type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>  

   <div id="programs"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        var table = new Tabulator("#programs", {
            ajaxURL:"./programs.json", // http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data
            //ajaxContentType:"json",
            height: 326,
            layout: "fitColumns",
            pagination: "local",
            paginationSize: 10,
            tooltips: true,
            index: "name",          
            columns: [{
                    title: "Name",
                    field: "name",
                    sorter: "string",                    
                    headerFilter: "input"
                },
                {
                    title: "Frequencies",
                    field: "freq",
                    sorter: "string",                    
                    headerFilter: "input"
                },                  
                {
                    title: "Database",
                    field: "db",
                    sorter: "string",                       
                    editor: "select",
                    width: 90,
                    headerFilter: true,             
                },               
                {
                    title: "Programm Info",
                    field: "info",
                    sorter: "string",
                    headerFilter: "input"
                },
            ],
            ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
              //url - the URL of the request
              //params - the parameters passed with the request
              //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

              return response.data; //pass the data array into Tabulator
           },
        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch() doesnt support local file access. But the browser will through the  tag, so if you make your programs.json be proper JS ...

```
programs.json :
let setData = [ { .... } ];

programs.html :
<html>
    <head>
...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="programs.json"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
...
        <script>
            new Tabulator("#programs",{
                data:setData,
...
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works when i open the programs.html locally on my PC. But when i load everything to a webserver it doesnt load the programs.json anymore. Is there something to change with the paths?

Comment: Nope, nothing different. Be sure that the 2 files are in the same location on the webserver, and that your webserver is configured to access and serve the file up. If you're using Firefox/Chrome, then F12 brings up the debugger where you can see network traffic and be sure the server is reponding properly. Which I can simulate by changing the filename in the HTML to say, "programs1.json". And if the server is serving it up properly, the debugger will let you see the file contents that it is serving up, to make sure it is as expected

Answer (score 0):

When i upload the html and json file to a webserver it gives following error -> "Error: 'setData' is undefined". Same error as when you press the "Run Code Snippet" button
Interestingly if you open this html locally on the PC it works fine.
Any suggestions why running on a webserver doesnt work?

programs.json:

```
let setData = [
           {
            "name": "Stomachache",
            "freq": "10000,5000,880,3000,95",
            "db": "XTR",
            "info": "Bauchschmerzen"
        }, {
            "name": "Headache",
            "freq": "380,2720,2489,2170,1800,1600,1550,880,832,787,776,727,465,444,1865,146,125,95,72,20,450,440,428,660",
            "db": "CAF",
            "info": "Kopfschmerzen"
        }, {
            "name": "Toothache",
            "freq": "3000,95,1550,880,787,776,727,650,625,600,28,35,28,110,100,60,428,680",
            "db": "XTR",
            "info": "Zahnschmerzen"
        }];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>  
  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="programs.json"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
<div id="programs"></div>
    <script>
        var table = new Tabulator("#programs", {
            data:setData,
            height: 326,
            layout: "fitColumns",
            pagination: "local",
            paginationSize: 10,
            tooltips: true,
            index: "name",          
            columns: [{
                    title: "Name",
                    field: "name",
                    sorter: "string",                    
                    headerFilter: "input"
                },
                {
                    title: "Frequencies",
                    field: "freq",
                    sorter: "string",                    
                    headerFilter: "input"
                },                  
                {
                    title: "Database",
                    field: "db",
                    sorter: "string",                       
                    editor: "select",
                    width: 90,
                    headerFilter: true,             
                },               
                {
                    title: "Programm Info",
                    field: "info",
                    sorter: "string",
                    headerFilter: "input"
                },
            ],
        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```